# python objects change attributes

Tags: python, list, oop

I am making a tank game and I have tank and bullet objects. When I fire, following method is executed:

```
def newshot(self,tank):
    shot = bullet()
    shot.loc = tank.loc
    shot.speed = tank.direction
    self.shots.append(shot)
```

loc is a list that show the location [x,y], speed and direction are lists that show the speed [dx,dy].

To move each of the bullets speed vector was added to its location in a for loop. But whenever I changed the location of the bullet, the location of my tank also changed (I printed out a tanks location before and after the for loop).
What I did that solved my problem was that instead of doing

```
shot.loc = tank.loc
```

I did

```
shot.loc = [tank.loc[0],tank.loc[1]]
```

**My question is where is the difference?**

Comment: You mean the tank followed the bullets?

Comment: You are appending a reference to one list in another list. It looks like you need to store a copy of the list instead.

Comment: I solved the problem, but the question was where the difference is between shot.loc = tank.loc and shot.loc = [tank.loc[0],tank.loc[1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copied the reference instead of the value, which meant the two variables were pointing at the same object.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.

The simplest way to copy the `tank.loc` list into `shot.loc` is to slice the whole list:

```
shot.loc = tank.loc[:]
```

But see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/768176 for other valid suggestions.

Comment: best solution, best description!

Answer (score 1):

When you use:

```
shot.loc = tank.loc
```

`shot.loc` and `tank.loc` are references to the same list.

To copy the list, use:

```
shot.loc = tank.loc[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `deepcopy` the list. ie:

```
import copy
shot.loc = copy.deepcopy(tank.loc)
```

here is a how it works:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = a
a[0][1] = 10
print a
# [[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print b   # b changes too -> Not a deepcopy.
# [[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]


import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
a[0][1] = 9
print a
#[[1, 9, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print b    # b doesn't change -> Deep Copy
#[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```